# Add hover effect to the child elements css/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have a HTML file which is auto generated from a JSON. On generating the DOM, I have layers with sub layers and sublayers ...etc.

Now on hovering each div, the border of the hovered layer must be visible. I tried adding :hover to the div, but it applies only to the main div. Others don't effect since it lies beneath it. Tried using pointer-events too still not working. Code added below. Thanks

```css
.layer {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.layer:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 215px; top: 79px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
      Layer
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
        Layer
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
          Layer
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">Layer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 153px; width: 256px; height: 57px;">Layer
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 130px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 29px; width: 39px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 27px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">Layer
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 496px; top: 147px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">Layer
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 219px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 496px; top: 219px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 291px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 373px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
      <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 8px; width: 89px; height: 23px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 89px; height: 23px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 162px; top: 33px; width: 700px; height: 475px;">
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 700px; height: 475px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1024px; height: 541px;">
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1024px; height: 541px;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: because you only hover on the upper most div? change the div width and height

Answer (score 1):

Essentially what happened was, because the 'bigger' divs were last in the DOM tree, they had priority. You need to put the 'bigger' elements first, then going down them getting smaller and smaller. Run the below code snippet and you'll see it works.

```css
.layer {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.layer:hover {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1024px; height: 541px;">
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1024px; height: 541px;"></div>
</div><div class="layer" style="left: 162px; top: 33px; width: 700px; height: 475px;">
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 700px; height: 475px;"></div>
</div><div class="layer" style="left: 215px; top: 79px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
  Layer
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
    Layer
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
      Layer
      <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">Layer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 153px; width: 256px; height: 57px;">Layer
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 130px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 29px; width: 39px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 27px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">Layer
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">Layer</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 496px; top: 147px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">Layer
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 219px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 496px; top: 219px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 291px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="layer" style="left: 220px; top: 373px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
  <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 8px; width: 89px; height: 23px;">
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 89px; height: 23px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
    <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>


  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: But how can I change the DOM structure, since it is auto generated from the JSON file?

Comment: Change the JSON file to be in a different order - do you have the JSON file? Can you include it in the question?

Comment: Ah! So the layers have layers within them. Interesting. Try this instead, for every parent, give it a z-index of 10, then, for each child add another 1 to the index. For example, a child of a child of a parent (3 deep) would have a z-index of 12. Set it via JavaScript when you're generating the code (jQuery would be `$(element).css("z-index", 10)`)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <style>
    .mainlayer {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
    }

    .layer:hover {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      pointer-events: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 215px; top: 79px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
          Layer
        </div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
          Layer
        </div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 234px; height: 35px;">
          Layer
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 220px; top: 153px; width: 256px; height: 57px;">Layer
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 130px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 29px; width: 39px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 27px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">Layer</div>
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;">Layer</div>
        </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 496px; top: 147px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">Layer
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;">Layer</div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 220px; top: 219px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 496px; top: 219px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 220px; top: 291px; width: 256px; height: 72px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 6.125px; width: 130px; height: 23px;"></div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 35.375px; width: 39px; height: 23px;"></div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 33px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 256px; height: 30px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 220px; top: 373px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 14px; top: 8px; width: 89px; height: 23px;"></div>
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 89px; height: 23px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
          <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;"></div>
        </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 162px; top: 33px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px;  width: 117px; height: 40px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="mainlayer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;">
        <div class="layer" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 117px; height: 40px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</body>

</html>
```